# Flutter Widgets don't get overridden accent color

Tags: flutter, themes

I have a dynamic theme in my app.
I set the theme using the following code:

```
    final ThemeData base = ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light, fontFamily: 'Simpler');
return base.copyWith(
  primaryColor: AppColors.appColor,
  accentColor: AppColors.secondaryColor,
  accentColorBrightness: Brightness.light,
  accentIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black)
);
```

This is set as the theme in my app

```
      child: MaterialApp(
    title: Provider.of<AppConfig>(context).appName,
    locale: selectedLocale.locale,
    theme: currentTheme.data,
    initialRoute: '/',
    onGenerateRoute: routes,
    localizationsDelegates: [
      AppLocalizationsDelegate(),
      FallbackCupertinoLocalisationsDelegate(),
      GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    ],
    supportedLocales: [
      Locale('en', 'US'),
    ],
  ),
```

The docs show that widgets such as a fab or a switch should be default be set to the themes accent color but for some reason the color the widgets get is the system default light blue accent color.
When I debug and check to see the accent color in the Theme.of(context) I see that the color is correct...

If I specificaly add the color change to the custom theme such as

```
    floatingActionButtonTheme: FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
    backgroundColor: AppColors.secondaryColor,
    foregroundColor: Colors.black,
  ),
```

The color is set as it should but I don't think that I should override all the properties in the ThemeData, it just dose'nt make sense.

Comment: To be sure, are you setting it in the app theme data as shown [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes#creating-an-app-theme)? The code you pasted does not "set" the theme, it just "creates" one.

Comment: @Edman Yes of course. I will update the question for clarity.

Comment: I got a sample running on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/edman/ac723b7c97b2e0edd7c89a465410365c), where setting the theme accent color changes the floating action button color as expected. Maybe your problem is somewhere else? Hmm this is weird though because you said `Theme.of(context).accentColor` displays the correct color.

Comment: @Edman It is really weird! I really have no idea why this isn't working as expected... Even when I use a breakpoint on app start when loading the app widget it seems as if the theme is configured correctly. I will further investigate... Thanks